# Can get my center alignment to work

Tags: css, xpages

I can't seem to get my page to center in the browser.  I've 'centered' everything I can think of. If I center anything else, the whole universe is going to be centered! :-)

Any tips would be appreciated.  Here's what I'm trying to center:

```
http://www.labware.com/usrmtgs/chCEC2014.nsf/home.xsp
```

Thanks
clem

Comment: Try adding this at the very top of your CSS stylesheet:   * { 
 align:center 
}

Comment: Actually when I saved your source code and saved it to my system and then viewed it in browser, it comes in the center. Dont know why its happening like that. Anyone can suggest what's happening?

Answer (score 5):

[EDIT]
This is really a case of the inheritance of CSS properties from the OneUI theme impacting how the block elements are playing with each other. Below is the work around if you want to preserve the OneUI theme.
[/EDIT]

For the div above the table, it's pulling a margin: 0 property from the core.css from the OneUI theme. I'd recommend overriding it by setting the div, via the inline style attribute, to display: block, then setting the table to display: inline-block.

[image]

Comment: +1 for visualising the answer using an animated gif!

Comment: Thanks @MarkLeusink. I used [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/), which I've found very useful lately.

Comment: Hi Eric.  Thanks!  That fixed the problem.  I ended up using the same technique for the language switcher.  I'll look into 'LICEcap' since I end up sending screen captures to explain things.  An animated gif would be much better.  Appreciate the help!  Clem

Comment: Glad I could help. I would recommend disabling the form, if it's not needed (from Per's answer) and if you liked it, would you mind marking the question answered? (trying to up my stats a little)

Comment: I guess user3718738 is me??  Yes, what you suggested worked.  See my reply Jun 17, '14

Comment: @user3718738 If the solution was useful, why not accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to your div (and remove text-align: center) to center the div:

```
margin: auto;
width: 500px;
```

You can adjust the width to whatever is most appropriate. A width of 500 pixels almost matches the picture (width 500 px) and the table border.

---

I would remove the table and style all of your "table" using divs.

Also, since you are not using form elements (for posting data and for partial refreshes) you can add `createForm="false"` to your XPage to remove the auto-generated form:

```
<xp:view ... createForm="false">
```

Comment: Completely correct on removing the unnecessary form tag, as it's impacting block element behavior; and use of divs over tables for screen flexibility. Obviously multiple ways to skin a cat ;-)